# Permission Error for python on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to download some files at regular intervals, remove the old ones and replace them with new files. First time it runs well, but the second time it throws an error.

```
def check_update():
    print ('looking for update')
    shutil.rmtree(config.destination)
    shutil.os.mkdir(config.destination)
    threading.Timer(60.0,check_update).start()

    def get_videos():
        response = requests.get(config.api)
        data = response.json()
        files = list()
        l = len(data)
        for i in range(l):
            files.append(data[i]['filename'])
        return files

    def get_newfiles(myfiles):
        for i in range(len(myfiles)):
            url = config.videos+myfiles[i]
            filename = wget.download(url)

    def move_files(myfiles):
        for i in range(len(myfiles)):
            file = myfiles[i]
            shutil.move(config.source_files+file,config.destination)

    def videos():
        files = set(get_videos())
        myfiles = list(files)
        get_newfiles(myfiles)
        move_files(myfiles)

    videos()
    print ("files are updated")
    res = requests.get(config.api)
    data = res.json()
    return data

data = check_update()
```

Here is the error.

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 1182, in run
   self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
 File "tornado.py", line 8, in check_update
   shutil.rmtree(config.destination)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
   return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
   onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
   os.unlink(fullname)
permissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Try to run this program from powershell (Run as administrator)

Comment: @NiranjRajasekaran: It's not permissions related since it ran the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when attempting to delete `config.destination` dir. That happens because either the dir itself or one (or more) of its children (may be a dir or a file) is opened in another process (could also be the **current** one).
Typical usecases that frequently lead to this situation:

- A *cmd* console is open in that dir. Just `cd` outside the dir and try removing it again
- A running program has a file opened

  - As an example could be a *Notepad* (or an *IDE*) that has opened a source file located in that dir.
  - But since it looks like you work with videos, maybe You wanted to check whether a downloaded file works and opened it in a video player.

  No matter what the case, closing that program would fix the issue
- This is specific to you: I don't know how `wget.download` works, but if it's not blocking (although according to the code it doesn't seem to be the case) maybe one video from your previous run is still downloading, hence it's open. Closing that *python* process would do (whether waiting til it finishes or killing it from *Task Manager*)

**Note**: When searching for the cause, you should try removing the dir from a file manager (e.g. *Windows Explorer*) to avoid the overhead introduced by the script.

Comment: Did your problem go away? (a computer restart would definitely resolve it, but I omitted it from the solution because it seems a bit too exaggerated).